# curl connect timeout not working

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I'm using CURL to connect to multiple xml feeds and process them when the page loads. Unfortunately, every once in awhile a page won't be responsive and my script will stall as well. Here's an example of the code that I'm working with. I set the timeout to 1 but that doesn't appear to be working.  I then set the timeout to 0.0001 just to test things today and it still pulled in xml feeds. Do you guys have any ideas on how to force curl to timeout when a script is taking forever.

```
foreach($urls as $k => $v) {
   $curl[$k] = curl_init();   
   curl_setopt($curl[$k], CURLOPT_URL, $v);
   curl_setopt($curl[$k], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl[$k], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl[$k],CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the difference between CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't give any useful info. Of course these are different options and of course we have to see the difference :)

Answer (score 37):

There are two different timeouts with curl -- see [`curl_setopt` manual's page](http://php.net/curl_setopt) :

> `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` 
> The number
>   of seconds to wait while trying to
>   connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

And :

> `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` 
> The maximum number
>   of seconds to allow cURL functions to
>   execute.

They both have a "millisecond" version : `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`, respectively.

In your case, you might want to configure the second one too : what seems to take time is not the connection, but the construction of the feed on the server side.

Comment: Thanks so much this was extremely helpful. I'm trying to test to see if it works and to do this I set the timeout to 1 like in the code below. I am parsing xmls with 50-100 elements so I would imagine it would take more than a millisecond. I expected to get no results but instead everything returned as normal.  

 curl_setopt($curl[$k], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1); 

Am I missing something?   Thanks a lot Pascal

Russ

Comment: really nice example there Pascal

Answer (score 0):

i am using Curl library for download a file from Apache Server. 
downloadFileWithCurlLibrary fonction has two inputs. 
FileUrl is the file will download form server. 
Example : www.abc.com/myfile.doc.
locFile is directory and file name you want to save.
Example:/home/projectx/myfile.doc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int downloadFileWithCurlLibrary(char *FileUrl,char *locFile)
{
    char dlFile[1024];
    CURL *curl_handle;
    FILE *pagefile;


    memset(dlFile,0x0,sizeof(dlFile));
    /* Create URL */

    sprintf(dlFile,"%s",FileUrl);

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* init the curl session */
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    /* Set timeout 3 min = 3*60 sec here. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800 );

    /* set URL to get here */
    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, dlFile) != CURLE_OK)
        return -1;

    /* Switch on full protocol/debug output while testing */
    //  if (curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L) != CURLE_OK)
    //    return -1;

    /* disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable and disable debug output */
    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L) != CURLE_OK)
        return -1;

    /* send all data to this function  */
    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data) != CURLE_OK)
        return -1;

    /* open the file */
    pagefile = fopen(locFile, "wb");
    if (pagefile)
    {

        /* write the page body to this file handle. CURLOPT_FILE is also known as
           CURLOPT_WRITEDATA*/
        if (curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FILE, pagefile) != CURLE_OK)
            return -1;

        /* get it! */
        if (curl_easy_perform(curl_handle) != 0)
            return -1;

        /* close the header file */
        fclose(pagefile);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    /* cleanup curl stuff */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would probably receive up votes if you explained this more and actually showed a demonstration of the callback functions.

Comment: When timeout is occured. This function return -1.

Comment: 1800s = 30 minutes